# How can I detect if any error was given by Helgrind(valgrind)

Tags: linux, valgrind

I have a bash script that needs to detect whether any error was given by Helgrind. I have tried using the following:

```
thread_race=$(valgrind --error-exitcode=10 --tool=helgrind ./$2.out $3; echo $?)
```

$2 is a .cpp file and $3 is an argument. However, this doesn't work because it doesn't actually change the exit code.

I would expect `thread race` to be 10 if any errors are detected, and something else otherwise.

Is there any way to know if helgrind has detected any errors at all and then save the answer? I'm using Ubuntu linux with clang++.

**EDIT:**
In both cases when helgrind detects an error, and doesn't detect an error, `thread_race` returns 134.

I have a similar test without helgrind that works perfectly fine;

```
leak=$(valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=55 ./$2.out $3 >/dev/null; echo $?)
```

This would change the exit code to 55 when an error is given. I have been notified that --leak-check=full is needed for proper exit codes, using that results in more errors when using helgrind:

```
thread_race=$(valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=10 --tool=helgrind ./$2.out $3; echo $?)
```

outputs

```
valgrind: Unknown option: --leak-check=full
```

and thread_race = 1

Comment: Does `valgrind` detect an error in your example case? What is the exit code? (run the equivalent of `valgrind --error-exitcode=10 --tool=helgrind ./$2.out $3; echo $?` manually) Instead of `thread_race=$(valgrind ...; echo $?)` simply use `valgrind ...; thread_race=$?`

Comment: When not using helgrind this works fine. The exit code changes appropriately.(running without it now, accidently posted). Valgrind does detect an error(I have made one intentionally), however, regardless of whether it detects one - it still doesn't change the exit code. Exit code is 134

Comment: Please add all information to the question. It is easier for everyone to help if all information is in one place.

Comment: Done. I'll update when necessary.

Comment: @Bodo, have any possible solution? No one replied/asked anything since your comment...

Comment: If no one replied this could mean that nobody knows an answer or that your question is not clear enough. Simplify your commands. You don't need `thread_race`, only a `valgrind` call with sample arguments followed by `echo $?`. Use sample file names instead of `$2` etc. Provide a small sample source code that contains a problem detected by helgrind. Maybe you can change the title and the question text to make it more clear. Suggested title "valgrind/helgrind exit code does not show if errors are detected". Make your question text easily readable. I don't know if someone can help. (I cannot.)

Comment: --leak-check=full is a memcheck option, you cannot use it with --tool=helgrind

Comment: And otherwise, it works perfectly for me:    xxx=$(./Inst/bin/valgrind --tool=helgrind --error-exitcode=123 ./helgrind/tests/tc05_simple_race ; echo $?)   echo $xxx gives 123